# workshop registration algorithm - multiple workshops & rounds

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

I'm currently working on a workshop registration system for students where students can register for several workshops. A student can choose from 5 workshops which are available in all 4 rounds. Each workshop has space for 19 students.

Now I want to make an algorithm that automatically registers a student and chooses a workshop for each round as efficient as possible.

A student cannot choose the same workshop in multiple rounds.

Current situation:

```
Round 1 - space available
Workshop1 - 1 
Workshop2 - 6
Workshop3 - 1
Workshop4 - 0
Workshop5 - 4

total 12 spaces available

Round 2 - space available
Workshop1 - 1
Workshop2 - 8
Workshop3 - -1
Workshop4 - 3
Workshop5 - 1

total 12 spaces available

Round 3 - space available
Workshop1 - 1
Workshop2 - 7
Workshop3 - 1
Workshop4 - 2
Workshop5 - 1

total 12 spaces available

Round 4 - space available
Workshop1 - 0
Workshop2 - 4
Workshop3 - 0
Workshop4 - 5
Workshop5 - 3

total 12 spaces available
```

What's the best way to approach this?

This is what I've tried to add a single student with workshops.

```
int[] chosenWorkshops;
bool workshopFound;
foreach(var round in rounds)
{
    workshopFound = false;
    foreach(var workshop in round.workshops.orderByDescending(q => q.space))
    {
        if(!chosenWorkshops.contains(workshop.ID) && workshop.space > 0)
        {
            chosenWorkshops.push(workshop.ID);
            workshopFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!workshopFound) break;
}

if(chosenWorkshops.length == rounds.length)
{
    var student = new Student();
    foreach(var workshopID in chosenWorkshops)
    {
        student.RegisterWorkshop(workshopID);
    }
} else {
    throw new InsufficientSpaceException();
}
```

The problem with this code is that it might run out of options on the last round because the available options in the last round were already taken in the earlier rounds.

Can anybody push me in the right direction please?

Comment: Add what you've tried so far so that we can help you with a "specific" problem that you are facing

Comment: Do you want us to make your homework?

Comment: I just added what I tried so far.

Comment: @Icepickle What makes you think this is homework. It isn't

Comment: No code and such a specific, well documented question, would lead me to such conclusions

Comment: As an extra question, does the student have a choice at which date he has to take the Workshop, or would you like to suggest an "optimal" track for all the students for the available rounds and courses? Or would you simply like to suggest which workshop+round would be the best for him with a free choice to pick another one?

Comment: @Icepickle I just want the algorithm to generate students and each student should be assigned to workshops with the most available space. Till the point that there are insufficient unique workshops available. Then it should throw an exception. The code in my question should describe the problem very clearly

Comment: I don't really understand the question; how does the total space relate to the values shown in the column 'space availabel'? What exactly do you mean by 'as efficient as possible'; efficiency in terms of algorithmic complexity or in terms of some objective function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question completely, but, if you want that your workshops are filled as good as possible and that every student should take all the courses, then I guess you could do it in the following way

You could create an extra class that contains a Subscription for a Round and implement that a round contains a reference to the workshop in question.

Then to Organize that data in an "optimal" way (where there are mostly courses with as many people as possible and all rounds + workshops are held) like this

```
class Organizer {
  public IList<Workshop> Workshops { get; } = new List<Workshop>();
  public IList<Student> Students { get; } = new List<Student>();
  public IList<Round> Rounds { get; } = new List<Round>();

  public void Add(Workshop workshop) {
    if (workshop == null || Workshops.Contains(workshop)) {
      return;
    }
    Workshops.Add( workshop );
  }

  public void Add(Student student) {
    if (student == null || Students.Contains(student)) {
      return;
    }
    Students.Add( student );
  }

  public void Add(Round round) {
    if (round == null) {
      throw new ArgumentException( "Round should be set!" );
    }
    if (round.Workshop == null) {
      throw new ArgumentException( "Round.Workshop must be set!" );
    }
    Rounds.Add( round );
    Add( round.Workshop );
  }

  public IList<Subscription> CreateSubscriptionsList(bool enableAverageAttendees = true) {
    IList<Subscription> results = new List<Subscription>();
    int totalRoomAvailable = Rounds.Sum( round => round.AvailableSpace ) / Workshops.Count;
    int totalUniqueRounds = Rounds.GroupBy( round => round.StartsAt.ToShortDateString() + round.EndsAt.ToShortDateString() ).Count();
    int averageStudentsPerRoundCount = (int)Math.Floor((totalRoomAvailable - (Students.Count * totalUniqueRounds)) / (double)Workshops.Count);

    // per round
    foreach ( var round in Rounds ) {
      // get all the students, with the nr of courses they are enlisted with already
      // and sort by ascending
      var additions = (from student in Students
                      select new { Student = student, CourseCount = results.Count( i => i.Student.Equals( student ) ) })
                      .OrderBy(i => i.CourseCount);

      // check how many should be added in this round
      int count = !enableAverageAttendees ? round.AvailableSpace : (averageStudentsPerRoundCount > 0 ? averageStudentsPerRoundCount : round.AvailableSpace + Math.Abs(averageStudentsPerRoundCount));

      // add all that don't attend a course at the same time, or did this course already
      foreach (var addition in additions ) {
        if (results.Any(subscription => subscription.Student.Equals(addition.Student) 
            && (round.Workshop.Equals(subscription.Round.Workshop) 
              || (round.StartsAt >= subscription.Round.StartsAt && round.EndsAt <= subscription.Round.EndsAt))
            )) {
          continue;
        }
        results.Add( new Subscription() { Round = round, Student = addition.Student } );
        count--;
        if (count <= 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return results;
  }
}
```

And if run with following parameters:

- 6 courses
- 3 rounds (a week apart)
- 15 students

The output would be something like:

```
Workshop C# course
Round #1: 11/17/2015 - 11/18/2015
Student 1
Student 2
Round #7: 11/24/2015 - 11/25/2015
Student 13
Student 14
Round #13: 12/1/2015 - 12/2/2015
Student 10
Student 11
Workshop HTML 5
Round #4: 11/17/2015 - 11/18/2015
Student 7
Student 8
Round #10: 11/24/2015 - 11/25/2015
Student 4
Student 5
Round #16: 12/1/2015 - 12/2/2015
Student 1
Student 2
Workshop JS course
Round #3: 11/17/2015 - 11/18/2015
Student 5
Student 6
Round #9: 11/24/2015 - 11/25/2015
Student 2
Student 3
Round #15: 12/1/2015 - 12/2/2015
Student 14
Student 15
Workshop ReactJS course
Round #6: 11/17/2015 - 11/18/2015
Student 11
Student 12
Round #12: 11/24/2015 - 11/25/2015
Student 8
Student 9
Round #18: 12/1/2015 - 12/2/2015
Student 5
Student 6
Workshop Vb.net course
Round #2: 11/17/2015 - 11/18/2015
Student 3
Student 4
Round #8: 11/24/2015 - 11/25/2015
Student 15
Student 1
Round #14: 12/1/2015 - 12/2/2015
Student 12
Student 13
Workshop Webdesign
Round #5: 11/17/2015 - 11/18/2015
Student 9
Student 10
Round #11: 11/24/2015 - 11/25/2015
Student 6
Student 7
Round #17: 12/1/2015 - 12/2/2015
Student 3
Student 4
```

And as a data structure, I have the following classes:

```
class Subscription {
  public Round Round { get; set; }
  public Student Student { get; set; }
}

abstract class IDIdentity {
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

class Workshop : IDIdentity {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Round : IDIdentity {
  public Workshop Workshop { get; set; }

  public DateTime StartsAt { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndsAt { get; set; }
  public int AvailableSpace { get; set; }
}

class Student : IDIdentity {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Constraint Satisfaction Problem Solver to solve this. For example, using [CSPNET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cspnet/)

If you create a class `Workshop` and a class `StudentSlot` that represents the students and their 4 time slots you could use `Variable<StudentSlot, Workshop>` to track the assignment of a Workshop to a given student time slot.

```
// The variables are the StudentSlots and the domain is the workshops they want to attend
IReadOnlyCollection<Variable<StudentSlot, Workshop>> studentAssignmentVariables = 
    studentSlots.Select(ss => new Variable<StudentSlot, Workshop>(ss, 
    studentChoices[ss.Student])).ToList();
```

You can then create a couple of constraints: One to check that each student only attends a workshop once:

```
var workshopsCanBeAttendedAtMostOnce = studentAssignmentVariables.GroupBy(x => x.UserObject.Student)
    .Select(gp => new AllDifferentConstraint<StudentSlot, Workshop>(gp));
```

And another constraint to check that no workshop has more than 19 students in it (you'll need a custom constraint for that).

Now you can ask the solver to solve it.

```
var problem = new Problem<StudentSlot, Workshop>(studentAssignmentVariables, constraints);
var solver = new RecursiveBacktrackSolver<StudentSlot, Workshop>();
var solution = solver.Solve(problem, CancellationToken.None);
```

The source code for CSPNET is on Github where you can see how recursive backtracking works to solve the problem given the constraints.

Full sample here: https://gist.github.com/IanMercer/d7670577d5e88ab2bdf6